# Extremely wide prediction interval

Tags: r, regression, prediction-interval

I am fitting a linear model to a data set with a lot of variance. Basically, I have sales for the first few months of similar, but not exactly the same objects, and am trying to predict sales a year from now. I am taking the log of the variables for variance stabilization. A simple version of the model looks like the following in R:

```
fit <- lm(log(futureSales) ~ log(salesToday), data=data)
```

The R-squared is about 0.8. I am then using the `predict` function on test data points not included in the training data set. The prediction interval is meaningless because of the high variance, ranging from 0 to an impossibly high number.

Is the prediction interval indicating that it is impossible to get an accurate prediction due to the amount of variability?

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit. How many data points do you have for training? You've simplified your model, but do you have variables other than just the sales? Do you have any time-related variables? It sounds like you have few data points, few variables, no time-related variables and you're not using a time-series method. (Non-time-series methods can be fooled into being over-confident in their results due to autocorrelation of time series data. You're lucky that didn't happen to you in this case.)

Comment: I have 200 data points. I do have other related variables, but I experience the same problem as I do with the simple one. I went with the simple model to try to make it easier while I look into the problem. I have variables measured in 2 different time periods, t1 and t2. For example, I have sales at t1 and want to predict sales at t2. Also, I have access to weekly sales data for a few months and would still need to project a year out. Do you think a time-series method would be appropriate using this data instead? Thank you for your help!